# Metadata of Check constraints SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, metadata, check-constraints, check-constraint

I have a SQL Server database that holds a table where a `varchar` column has a check constraints on it to make sure only a few different words can be entered as a value (names).

Like this

```
CONSTRAINT chk_Names CHECK (name IN ('John', 'Eva', 'Carl', 'Fred'))
```

What I want do do is to populate a combobox in java with these names, and I don't want to manually enter them since they might change in the database. I want to populate it from metadata.

But I haven't been able to find a way to get the information from the database either with the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` or `sys.objects` (or from DatabaseMetaData in java for that matter)

I'm quite new to SQL Server but is it possible to get that information somehow?

Regards
/Fred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should move the list of names to a table.  You're Java form could select the data from the table.

And, because the data can change, it will be better to update the table than to change the check constraint.  You can change the check constraint to a foreign key constraint too.

You can also find the check-constraint definitions in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS`.  The expression is in the `CHECK_CLAUSE` column; and, you'll have to extract the values from the expression.

Comment: the name is only a small part in the table, i cant move it out as a separate table im afraid

Comment: Added data for INFORMATION_SCHEMA.